# Return entity with latest timestamp matching a userId LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities

I am stuck on this. I have two tables: Users2Users and ActivityLog. I want to look up the list of Users2Users that are a user's friends and return each of their latest activity based on its Timestamp, then check what type it is.

```
Users2Users
int UserId
int TypeOfLink
int FriendId

ActivityLog
int Type
int UserId
DateTime Timestamp
```

The thing that seems to be troubling me is getting the ActivityLog entity rather than its Timestamp value.

My friendList query looks like this:

```
var friendList = (from u in db.Users2Users
where u.UserId == userId || u.FriendId == userId
&& u.TypeOfLink == 2 // confirmed as friend
orderby u.User.ScreenName ascending
select u).Distinct().ToList();
```

After that I was going to try a foreach, but how do I return the ActivityLog entity rather than the Timestamp?

```
// get their last activity
foreach (var user in domusers)
{
    var act = (from a in db.ActivityLogs
    where a.UserId == user.UserId
    select a.Timestamp).Max();
    // other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can order the entries by `Timestamp` and the pick the first element:

```
var act = db.ActivityLogs
  .Where(a => a.UserId == user.UserId)
  .OrderByDescending(a => a.Timestamp)
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or using query syntax:

```
var act = (from a in db.ActivityLogs 
where a.UserId == user.UserId
orderby a.Timestamp descending
select a).FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that if there are no elements in the source collection you will get a `null` result.

Using `OrderByDescending` is slightly ineffecient because it will sort all the activities. It is more efficient to perform a single pass over the collection and find the element with the latest `Timestamp`. You can do that using `Aggregate`. Here I assume that you are able to create a "null" `Activity` where the `Timestamp` property has the default (and minimal value) for `DateTime`:

```
var nullActivity = new Activity(); // nullActivity.Timestamp == DateTime.MinValue
var activity = db.ActivityLogs
   .Where(a => a.UserId == user.UserId)
   .Aggregate(
     nullActivity,
     (accumulate, value) => value.Timestamp >= accumulate.Timestamp ? value : accumulate
   );
if (activity != nullActivity)
  // The latest activity was found
```

If you can't create a "null" activity as the seed for `Aggregate` you can use an anonymous type to keep track of the latest timestamp and the associated activity but it is slightly more tedious to do.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think in your first bit of code the Where is missing the lambda? Where(a => a.UserId == user.UserId)

Comment: @testpattern: Thanks for pointing it out. It should be fixed now.

Comment: Martin, I'll try this out a bit later and let you know. Thanks for your help.